# Data not shown in UITableView below button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, button

I created UI for Iphone that has a button and label above tableview. The problem is that data doesn't show in table despite setting it in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. 
 I get this:
[image]

This is my code for controller of third tab. Header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   @interface ThirdView : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource> {
//model
NSMutableArray *podatki;
//view
 UITableView *myTableView;
 }

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *podatki;
@property(nonatomic,retain) UITableView *myTableView;

-(IBAction)pritisnuGumb:(UIButton *) sender; //

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "ThirdView.h"

@implementation ThirdView

  @synthesize podatki;
  @synthesize myTableView;

   -(void)viewDidLoad{

myTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]    style:UITableViewStylePlain]; 
myTableView.delegate = self; 
myTableView.dataSource = self; 

myTableView.autoresizesSubviews = YES; 

podatki = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    

[podatki addObject:@"Sunday"];
[podatki addObject:@"MonDay"];
[podatki addObject:@"TuesDay"]; 

[super viewDidLoad];
//self.view = myTableView;

 }

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return [podatki count];
 }

 -(IBAction)pritisnuGumb:(UIButton *) sender {

  NSLog(@"buca");
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];   
}

cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 4; 
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone; 

NSString *naslov = [podatki objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = naslov;    

return cell;
   }

     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"kliknu na vrstico");

   }

  - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
  {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
 }

  - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
  {
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
 }

 #pragma mark - View lifecycle



  - (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
 }

  - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

 - (void)dealloc {
[podatki release];
[super dealloc];
  }

 @end
```

If i uncomment line "self.view = myTableView;" i get tableview with data but label and button above it disappear (tableview is fullscreen).

What am i doing wrong here?

[image]
@Jennis:
I tried your solution and data inside table is now visible but upper part is squeezed like this:

Comment: Now you just need to assign frame position to your UITableView by giving  [myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake(<#CGFloat x#>, <#CGFloat y#>, <#CGFloat width#>, <#CGFloat height#>)]. Just give appropriate values for x y and width height according to your requirement. It should work now i guess. If this resolves your issue please accept the answer.

Comment: I had to set [myTableView setFrame:CGRectMake ......] like you said and REMOVE [self.view sendSubviewToBack:myTableView] to make it work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you can do like

> [self.view addSubview:myTableView];
>
> [self.view sendSubviewToBack:myTableView].

hope it helps

Comment: i updated my question to show what happens when i add your lines.